# Removing DVI connectors stuck in video card ports

Tags: cable, port

I need some help removing a couple of DVI connectors which are stuck in my video card ports. I don't know why they were screwed in so tightly in the first place but they won't move. I need to replace hardware in the machine, but doing so with the cables connected and the box in its current position is nearly impossible. I've tried pliers with grips to loosen the screws holding the cable, and I've tried a screwdriver, the latter ended up breaking off the plastic. Neither worked.

I'm at a loss as to what to do and I'm very frustrated. Can I get some suggestions?

Comment: Try jiggling the main part of the plug constantly while you try to turn the screws.

Comment: ^^+1 Usually the posts start moving or the screws come out with the posts

Comment: Or just use small hacksaw to break DVI connectors. After that you can't screw new ones in, but you can still plug those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about unscrewing the posts with the cable. get hold of a 5mm spanner and remove the cable, complete with the posts off the back of the card. Once removed, the bending moment that is interfering with you unscrewing the connector is gone which should make it easier to remove the posts with pliers and a 5mm spanner or nut driver. By holding the shaft with a pair of pliers you will avoid damaging the screw heads and then the only concern will be shearing off the threads inside the posts which is, unfortunately, an unavoidable risk.

Answer (score 0):

put a drop of [WD40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WD-40) on the screw and wait 1hr. then try